# Magento Multiwebsite shared login and logged in while switching

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, customer-session

I'm trying to share `customer` b/w two `magento` website with one `backend`, so here is my scenario,

Main website is `www.abc.com` & the second website is `pro.abc.com`, If a customer logged in site `A` he should be logged in Site `B` if he switch site.

[Share login details on multiple websites in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55349/share-login-details-on-multiple-websites-in-magento) i have tried this method but didn't work at all for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That answer is correct. Please share the steps, values and code you changed

Comment: I've tried above method but its only work b/w store not for multiwebsite

Comment: Gotcha. I might find the time to add an answer soon

Comment: Hey Halk , If you got time can you post the solution. I'm still wondering on this

Comment: any success i am also looking for solution